# I need a "Choose from existing content" popin

Tags: custom-field, customization, admin, metabox

I'd like to create a field that allows the admin to select from other existing post types.  Specifically, I want to create an options box to choose which events display on the homepage.

For now, I've just put a "on the homepage" checkbox on each event, but this does not help with ordering or reviewing the list of "featured" events.

The ideal UX is a meta box added to only the homepage admin screen, that allows the user to add/remove existing events a list and reorder them before republishing the homepage.  It would have an "add event" button, which when clicked, opens a post selector similar to the popin you get when you link text in the WYSIWYG.  "Insert/edit link", "... link to existing content".

I suppose I could just build my own popin, but I'd be happy to find out I could reuse this "post selection popin" that the link button uses.

Comment: What is a _popin?_

Comment: I'm referring to a modal popup box, which is simply a floating element in the page.  As opposed to an actual popup, which is a new window, typically opened with `window.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) can do this.

A Custom Field of the `Relation` type is needed. When creating it, enable `Is Repeatable`, select the desired `Output Filter` and the `Association`.
[image]
<sup>:...*click to More Info*</sup>

Make sure to enable `Standardize Custom Fields` for **Pages** in the `Content Types` tab of the plugin.

With all set, a Meta Box with the relationship/repeatable/sortable Custom Field will appear in all pages (looks like this will need a custom hack to only display it in `$post->ID == homepage_ID`).
This CF opens a thickbox where *all post types* can be searched/selected as a `Relation` (maybe another hack).

---

The plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) can do it all without hacks, but the `Repeater` is a premium add-on.